# Adding symbol in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to add a special symbol in my application (windows forms) using c#, the symbol that i wanna add like the following:

> ɸ

But, i don't know how to add the symbol or when user click the button, that symbol will appear on the textbox in winforms.

Anyone know how? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the character codes? http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0278/index.html

Comment: How do i used it in the windows forms sir? could you please give me an example on how to use it? Thank you

Comment: Character code for 'ɸ' is u0278

Comment: How do i use character code in winforms sir? could you please give me an example on how to use it? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried by changing **Font** property of textbox to **symbola** font. This might help you...